# how to access NSObject class from naviagation based app?

Tags: iphone

Im thinking a program that has made up by navigation bar with multiple views. so basically I want to access data(& storing data) to one same object class through the whole stack of navigation. for example, 1. choose a picture from firstview, store the picture to the object class. 2. change to other view and access the picture from the smae object class. 3. as a next step on the other view, also can access and store the data to this object class.

what I want to know now is how to maintain and access the same file from the all different levels of the program. please give me some tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `UIImageView` or other `NSObject` a property of the `rootViewController`, and then access it by:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *theRootViewController = appDelegate.rootViewController;
NSObject *myObject = theRootViewController.myobject;
```

However, if what you're passing is an `NSArray` or `BOOL` or `float` or `int`, then you can also consider using `NSUserDefaults` to save and load from anywhere within the app.